# Intellij Synchronizing output directories ..

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am trying to build a project, run it in debug mode and i keep getting "Synchronizing output directories" in Intellij. It takes around 5-10 minutes for an actual build. The project is almost empty and is stored on local drive. I tried to invalidate the catche but has not worked. Out of ideas .. anyone had any similar issues?

Comment: Most likely, some of your data is on a network drive or in your profile which is being synchronized with a network drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, some of your data is on a network drive or in your profile which is being synchronized with a network drive.

If you are on windows, try moving your .IdeaXXX/system directory and your work directory to somewhere else on your C: drive.

Comment: Interesting. I have the same problem, but I'm not on Windows and haven't bothered setting up any network drives. But I see that message an awful lot every time I build something and I get the "reindexing" taking forever when I tab back to the IDE from somewhere else - followed by multiple minutes or hours of choppy UI until whatever problem is happening has finished with whatever it's doing.

Comment: @Trejkaz When I switched to developing on an SSD most disk IO problems went away. I suspect it is still doing a lot of IO, but it now happens so much faster.

Comment: I'm on an SSD already too. I'm not entirely sure it's IO though because when I jstack the IDEA process, I see it doing a hash map lookup on the EDT...

Comment: @Trejkaz I have seen similar. IDEA still does too much work on the EDT.

Comment: deleting/renaming .idea folder in project root helps